# Async image download with header Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to download an image asynchronously with this library 
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-asynchronous-image-caching-independently

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  GalleryImageCell* cell = [collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  PSGalleriesImage* imagen = [self.Images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  [cell.Image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagen.link]];

  return cell;
}
```

The image is downloading and working good, but the server is returning a placeholder image because I'm not sending the auth_token. The auth token it's suppose to be sent in the header X-PS-Auth-Token

Is there a way to download an image async adding a header?

Comment: You need to find in this library where the request is being created and then set the auth token

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to find it, but with some minor changes i manage to change the headers thanks a lot. ill post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Claudio said, i just manage to change the library a it did the trick. Here i post the code:

this goes in the SDWebImageDownloader.m:

```
- (id)init
{
if ((self = [super init]))
{
    _executionOrder = SDWebImageDownloaderFIFOExecutionOrder;
    _downloadQueue = NSOperationQueue.new;
    _downloadQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2;
    _URLCallbacks = NSMutableDictionary.new;

    //CHANGES HERE
    NSMutableDictionary* headers =  [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [headers setObject:@"image/webp,image/*;q=0.8" forKey:@"Accept"];
    [headers setObject:@"image/webp,image/*;q=0.8" forKey:@"Accept"];
    [headers setObject:[AppData GetSessionToken] forKey:@"X-PS-Auth-Token"];
    _HTTPHeaders = headers;
    //CHANGES HERE

    _barrierQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.hackemist.SDWebImageDownloaderBarrierQueue",   DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
  }
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the library you can set your http headers into the imageDownloader, probably on your applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
-(void)configureSDWebImage
{
    SDWebImageDownloader *webImageDownloader = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager].imageDownloader;
    [webImageDownloader setValue:@"YourHTTPValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"YourHTTPHeader"];
}
```